# Terraform keeps deploying the Azure Function App Settings again and again

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have deployed Azure Function App using Terraform. Eventhough there are no changes, everytime I run the Terraform pipeline I see it is trying to add the below settings again and again. Can someone explain what might be wrong or if this could be an Bug?

```
      + "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING"                       = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;......"
      + "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE"                                           = "...."
```

**Note:** Using Terraform Provider Version: `3.24.0`

Comment: The terraform plan command should tell you what is causing that replacement to happen

Comment: Could you please add any code bases or errors describing the exact problem, either on the plan or in the application? so that it will be easy to replicate the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the Terraform provider version. Tried to replicate the scenario and haven't faced any issues with the below code.
With the new version "3.24.0," the following two lines of code must be added.

Referred code from this official Hashi Corp site [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app)

```
storage_account_name  =  azurerm_storage_account.demo.name
storage_account_access_key  =  azurerm_storage_account.demo.primary_access_key
```

**Step1:
Main tf file as follows:**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "**********"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "demo" {
  name                     = "*****"
 location             = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "demo" {
  name                = "******-service-plan"
 location             = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "demo" {
  name                      = "******"
  location                   = " ${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.demo.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.demo.primary_connection_string}"
  version                   = "~2"
  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION                 = "~2"
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME                    = "dotnet"
    WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING    = "${azurerm_storage_account.demo.primary_connection_string}"
    WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE                        = "swarnademotest"
  }
  site_config {
    always_on   = "true"
  }
}
```

**Provider tf  file as follows**

```
terraform {
  
      required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
           source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
           version = "~> 2.99" // for "3.24.0" 
             }
           }
 }

 provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

run below commands

```
terraform plan 
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

**up on running the apply**

[image]

**Verification**
[image]

[image]

When ran plan again,

```
terraform plan
```

there were no changes on the code.  Everything is working as expected. [ All changes which shown in screenshot are tag related]
[image]

on apply also no changes on the portal
[image]